# Debugging C applications in MonoDevelop fails

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, monodevelop

debugging in MonoDevelop does not work for me. First of all, I have installed MonoDevelop, GNU Debugger plugin and ctags through Ubuntu software center and I'm using Ubuntu 10.10.

When I press "Debug" it goes into debug mode but very quickly returns to "normal mode". My simple application contains some `scanf` so it should wait for input and I have also set a lot of breakpoints.

My application works perfectly when I run it without debugging and it debugs fine if I use `gdb` manually. Of cause, I've tried rebooting and installing multiple times.

Any ideas on what goes wrong?

**Update:**
I have checked the MonoDevelop log and it goes like:

```
OnTargetEvent, type - TargetExited
...
```

Thanks, Lasse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It have now been fixed :) : https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=624776

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you [file a bug](http://monodevelop.com/Developers/Reporting_Bugs).

You might want to check for errors in the MD log (~/.config/MonoDevelop/log) and the debugger output pad. Also, are you using an external console?

Comment: I will check the log :) I'm just using standard tools so I guess no. I'm new to MonoDevelop so it could be me just fooling around ;) (I have updated the question with the log)